# need efficient database model

Tags: php, mysql

I have a project where clients can submit changes, administrators can see the proposals and either accept, edit and approve, edit and send back to the client for approval, or deny them.

I am going to need 2 sets of data which is going to be a nightmare because I want to preserve the original proposal  when edits have been made, in case someone doesn't like the edit and wants to revert back to the original.

Here is my current system which I think needs to be more efficient, I need a better idea.

I need a status for every field, because I want to see exactly what field has been edited.

```
mySQL

Table  proposal_deal 

+----------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|  deal_id | name       |name_status   | price        | price_status |
+----------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|  1       | deal 1     | 1            |12.00         | 1            |    
+----------+------------+------------- +--------------+--------------+

Table  deal 

+------+---------+-----------+--------------+
| id   |deal_id | name       |price         | 
+------+--------+------------+--------------+
|  1   | 1      | deal 1     |12.00         | 
+------+--------+------------+------------- +
```

These tables have a lot of fields, so there are a lot of status columns as well.  I am wondering if a better approach would be to add a third table called status that would house all the field status info like this.

```
mySQL 

Table  proposal_deal

+----------+------------+-------------+
|  deal_id | name       |price        |
+----------+------------+-------------+
|  1       | deal 1     |12.00        |   
+----------+------------+-------------+

Table  deal 

+------+---------+-----------+--------------+
| id   |deal_id | name       |price         | 
+------+--------+------------+--------------+
|  1   | 1      | deal 1     |12.00         | 
+------+--------+------------+------------- +

Table status 

+------+--------+-------------+--------------+
| id   |deal_id | column_name |status        | 
+------+--------+-------------+--------------+
|  1   | 1      | name        | 1            | 
+------+--------+-------------+------------- +
```

What is going to be easier for design purposes as well as efficiency when making a lot of call to a DB?

I've already started with the first approach, buts its giving me a headache, but I don't want to change if the other approach is going to be the same..

Anyone have an opinion(I'm sure you do) or a alternate approach?

thanks

Comment: "As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."

Comment: if you are using some kind of ORM library it might be easier to just before update save a timestamped / person responsible copy in another table.

Comment: We **all** need an efficient database model!

Comment: Start with third normal form. Then use `EXPLAIN` to figure out what indexes are required for the queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, summary:

- `deals` are a one-off between two clients
- `clients` are people
- `proposals` form the guts of the `deals`, and there can only be one active per `deal`
- `proposals` have a status: `approved`, `declined`, `pending`. A `client` needs to approve them
- All history needs to be preserved on the following: `proposals`, `deals`

Following these guidelines, I would set it up as follows:

**deals**

```
id
name
proposal_id (FK proposals.id, UPDATE:CASCADE, DELETE:SETNULL)
client_id (FK clients.id, UPDATE:CASCADE, DELETE:SETNULL)
company_id (FK clients.id UPDATE:CASCADE, DELETE:SETNULL)
```

**proposals**

```
id
name
price
(more data fields)
modified_by (FK clients.id UPDATE:CASCADE, DELETE:SETNULL)
```

**status**

```
id
proposal_id (FK proposals.id UPDATE:CASCADE, DELETE:RESTRICT)
status
modified_by (FK clients.id UPDATE:CASCADE, DELETE:RESTRICT)
```

Add timestamps as you see fit. I would personally do the proposal edition using an `UPDATE` trigger that would duplicate the row before update, and then update the row accordingly. This guarantees that you have the set of foreign keys necessary to track all your status changes.

Oh, and the latest proposal in a deal should also be changed in the `deals` table. You can also do this with a trigger to make your life easier.

Comment: Thans man, I like this approach, I don't have any experience with triggers, so I guess I'll have to do some more reading on that.  Why and where would I want to use timestamps as well?

Comment: @vinylDeveloper: I'd add created_at and modified_at timestamps to status, proposal and deal, personally. This is to tell you when stuff was added and modified. Triggers: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers.aspx . They're literally automatic actions that happen based on another action (in this case, `UPDATE`)

Comment: if I want a status for every field in the proposals table, how would you set that up? This is so I can track exactly what field has been edited. Not just the whole deal?

Comment: @vinylDeveloper: create a `history` table with a trigger on UPDATE for proposals. whenever an UPDATE is done, insert a row in history.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a lot of reads/writes will be better with first approach and at the same time harder to maintain while 2nd approach is easier to maintain and might prove itself more useful at later times (should you need some stats from the tables)\

I personally would go with second or pick mongodb or similar if you like the first approach better.